# Simple JQuery Flash Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I could use help building jQuery flash cards.

Right now each flash card has a front side div and back side div. When a user clicks on the front side it should hide the front side and show the back side. The problem is right now all sides show on a single click.

When a user clicks on a card it reveals all of the other cards (not good).
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".flashcard-FRONT").click(function() {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  $(".flashcard-BACK").css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

```css
.holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.flashcard-FRONT {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  border: 7px #FFF solid;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px #00000042;
}

.flashcard-BACK {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  border: 7px #2b2b2b solid;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px #00000042;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="holder">

  <!-- START: FLASH CARD 1 -->
  <!-- FRONT SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-FRONT">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- BACK SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-BACK">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
    <p>Use interview resources to make the best hiring decisions and build diverse teams.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END: FLASH CARD 1 -->


  <!-- START: FLASH CARD 2 -->
  <!-- FRONT SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-FRONT">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- BACK SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-BACK">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
    <p>Use interview resources to make the best hiring decisions and build diverse teams.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END: FLASH CARD 2 -->

  <!-- START: FLASH CARD 3 -->
  <!-- FRONT SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-FRONT">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- BACK SIDE -->
  <div class="flashcard-BACK">
    <h3>Hiring Decisions</h3>
    <p>Use interview resources to make the best hiring decisions and build diverse teams.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END: FLASH CARD 3 -->

</div>
<!-- end holder -->
```

View on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/bvRqLE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click event handler is selecting all the div's with the "flashcard-BACK" class. You need to change it to only select the one that's needed. With your current markup you can do this by replacing:

```
$(".flashcard-BACK").css("display", "inline-block");
```

with

```
$(this).next().show();
```

However, you might consider wrapping each of the cards, both front and back inside a parent div like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">...</div>
  <div class="back">...</div>
</div>
```

then change your jquery handler to this:

```
$('.front', '.card').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings('.back').show();
});

$('.back', '.card').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings('.front').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jimmy Baker!

I followed your advice but now a new problem has risen. My cards are jumping around, not perfectly aligned. Can you help with the CSS logic, too? https://codepen.io/matie/pen/bvRqLE

Comment: To align flash cards to top, give each of them style "vertical-align: top;".

Answer (score 2):

one solution is use the jQuery.next() function:

```
$( ".flashcard-FRONT" ).click(function() {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  $(this).next().css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

If i must do this i wrap all the pairs into a div wrapper, and with the click I get the parent wrapper and the front card into the wrapper. With this solution the div's order it's not important at all.